# Azure Oauth: Trying to get access token but getting invalid_grant error [solved]

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

Following is my APP's setting:

- Web Redirect URL:

  - http://localhost/login/token
- Single Redirect URL:

  - http://localhost/login/token
- Implicit grant and hybrid flows

  - Access tokens (used for implicit flows)
  - ID tokens (used for implicit and hybrid flows)
- Supported account types

  - Accounts in this organizational directory only

This is the URL I used for getting authorization_code:

```
// Line breaks for legibility only

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={{ClientID}}&
response_type=id_token&
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Flogin%2Ftoken&
scope=openid&
response_mode=form_post&
nonce=678910
```

It works. Then I try to use following request to get access token:

```
URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Method: POST
Header: Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body (Line breaks for legibility only):
  client_id={{ClientID}}&
  client_secret={{ClientSecret}}&
  scope=openid&
  code={{authorization_code}}&
  grant_type=authorization_code&
  redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Flogin%2Ftoken
```

However, it shows error:

```json
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid. Trace ID: 12f61376-918d-421e-bc24-8fbeaa618300 Correlation ID: 1559c807-fcb0-4898-b656-bbb918424a95 Timestamp: 2023-12-12 07:08:47Z",
  "error_codes": [
    9002313
  ],
  "timestamp": "2023-12-12 07:08:47Z",
  "trace_id": "12f61376-918d-421e-bc24-8fbeaa618300",
  "correlation_id": "1559c807-fcb0-4898-b656-bbb918424a95",
  "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=9002313"
}
```

PS: I use Java and I do not use any oauth library

Comment: Is there really a `&` missing between `grant_type=authorization_code` and `redirect_uri=...`, or did that just get lost when you formatted this to show here?

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, it just a mistake when formatting. I have fixed it

Comment: `code={{authorization_code}}`- not sure how you would have gotten any `authorization_code` to begin with here. `response_type=id_token` means you will get a token back directly. To _get_ any code to exchange for a token, your response type would have to include `code` to begin with.

Comment: `{{authorization_code}}` is from `id_token` parameter of `http://localhost/login/token`

Comment: With `response_type=id_token` you do not get an authorization code, you get an access token directly.

Comment: try this get request and obtain the auth code in url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=client_id
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Flogin%2Ftoken
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid
&state=12345

Comment: then use the auth code to try to get the access token again.... I trust it is much easier to show you a correct url rather than troubleshoot the weird error... we have `session_state and state` behind the auth code in the url  https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1A89.png

Comment: @CBroe @TinyWang, thank you. I changed `response_type=id_token` 
to `response_type=code` then this issued is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

> Note that, the error `Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid` usually occurs if you are passing **invalid** values in token parameters.

In my case, I ran below **authorization request** in browser and got **`code`** value in address bar after signing in like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=appId
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/login/token
&response_type=code
&response_mode=query  
&scope=openid 
&state=12345
```

[image]

When I passed **invalid** or **extra** characters in **`code`** parameter value like *session_state* while generating token via Postman, I got same error like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type: authorization_code
client_id: appId 
client_secret: secret 
scope: openId
code: <code_with_invalid_parameter_value>
redirect_uri: http://localhost/login/token
```

**Response:**

[image]

You should remove this part  `&state=12345&session_state=`  from  **`code`**  parameter value to **resolve** the error as suggested by *@Tiny Wang*.

Your valid  **`code`**  value should be this:

[image]

When I passed **valid** `code` value, I got the tokens successfully in **response** like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type: authorization_code
client_id: appId 
client_secret: secret 
scope: openId
code: paste_code_from_above
redirect_uri: http://localhost/login/token
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, use `response_type=code` to **resolve** the error by replacing `response_type=id_token` while fetching the authorization code.

Comment: The main reason of my issues is `response_type=id_token` not `response_type=code`. After changing to `code`, I can get access token.

Comment: Edited the answer by adding this point.